# SVG graphic in Android

Tags: android, svg

My question is about scalable vector graphics focused on Android.

I know that the advantage of using vector images instead of png is that you can draw it in almost every device without modifying it. The drawback is that they're very slow.

But if you convert them into png images during the runtime and then you serialize them? You obtained all the advantages without drawbacks? Or there are other reasons to avoid svg?

Comment: I think this question is too broad and just prompts discussion about what tech to use. SVGs are typically more compact than PNGs for simple shapes and they can be drawn at any size which can't be said for PNGs. On the other hand, drawing a very complex SVG requires more processing than drawing a PNG and you'll need a modern browser or rendering library to render SVG. The right choice depends on what you need.